# Apply Function to while loop in Java

Tags: java, function, lambda, predicate

I have `while` loop which is supposed to run while `condition1` is true or while `condition2` is true. `1` or `2` case depends on some initial boolean condition.

Now I implemented this as a ternary operator, but I'd like to understand how this can be done using a Predicate, and lambda expressions. 
Can someone provide an example please? How can I declare a Function variable and put it into the `while` loop condition?

```
boolean initialCondition = stopBtn.getText().length() > 0;

while(initialCondition ? stopBtn.waitToBeHidden() : stopBtn.isDisplayed()) {
    if (a++ < 5) {
        stopBtn.click();
    }
}
return this;
```

Comment: Could you show some pseudo-code of what you want to achieve? I don't quite know where you want to apply a predicate...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think even in a predicate you'd need your if/else.

If you provide more code it would probably be easier to see what you're aiming to do. One way of using a predicate (that you can then pass around etc.) would be:

```
Predicate<StopBtnClass> pred = btn -> btn.getText().length() > 0 ? btn.waitToBeHidden() : btn.isDisplayed();

while(pred.test(stopBtn)) {
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, I understand regarding if/else in predicate. I just confused when tried to apply predicate in 'while' condition. I forgot about .test(...) method. But your example works great for me, than you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `BooleanSupplier` to model the condition:

```
java.util.function.BooleanSupplier condition = stopBtn.getText().length() > 0 ?
     stopBtn::waitToBeHidden : 
     stopBtn::isDisplayed;

while (condition.getAsBoolean()) {
    ...
}
```